# What is the difference between it was a good memory and it is a good memory?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense

If you say it was a good memory does it mean that in the present time it is no longer a good memory to you?

I don't know which one to use in the situation when I describe my memory in the past. In terms of my own understanding if you use past tense it means the action is finished. But what if I just explain what happened in the past and I still think it's a good memory do I use present tense? But in the meantime, I know you have to keep the verb tense consistent when speaking/writing so I am very confused about which one to use.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it might be a bit confusing to speak about **good** memories. A good memory is simply a *retentive* one. Good memories may simply be clear or accurate ones. For now, let's use 'happy' instead.

Secondly, we generally speak of *memories* (plural): "I have happy memories of that place." Or we might say, "I never liked that place, though I do have *one* happy memory of it." To say, "I have **a** happy memory of him" is unusual, and you will certainly be asked for details: what **is** this one happy memory?

If your memories of X are (present tense) happy ones, it is enough to say, "I have happy memories of X."

If you tell us you **had**, or **used to have**, happy memories of somewhere or someone, we will expect you to explain why they are no longer happy. Perhaps you discovered something ghastly about the place/person.

You might also say, "I have happy memories of our first few years together: before it all went wrong."

We can talk about contrasting memories:

> I had happy memories of a lake in a forest I used to visit as a child.
> I went back to visit it recently and realised it was only a muddy pond in a
> small wood. Now I find I have *two* memories (or mental pictures) of
> it: as it is and as it was.

By the way, as well as happy/unhappy memories we talk about pleasant/unpleasant ones and **fond** ones. The expression "I remember it fondly" is useful. See the examples [here](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fond).

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize that even native speakers do not always use English with skill. People do not always strive for the best expression, especially in speech and informal writing.

> It was a good memory

is discussing the past. That does not entail that the memory is good or not good now. The language leaves that open though some may interpret, correctly or incorrectly, the ambiguity as deliberate.

If, however, you wanted to imply that it is no longer a good memory, it is clearer to say

> It was once a good memory.

Of course, there is no need to imply anything.

> It was once a good memory, but no longer

makes the contrast explicit.

On the other hand,

> It is a good memory

does not entail that at some past times it was not a good memory. Some may interpret it that way because it is not explicit. If you want to suggest without affirming a change, you can say

> It is now a good memory

which implies that it has not always been a good memory.

But again, there is no need to imply. You can be explicit with

> Now it is a good memory, but it once was not.

English has lots of words. Use them to make your meaning clear.